# Get the branch of collection without the sibling elements, searching by property

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, algorithm, tree

I have the object with the next structure:

```
let array = [
      {
        name: 'Name1',
        items: [
          {
            name: 'Name1.1',
            items: [
              { id: '1', name: 'Name1.1.1' },
              { id: '2', name: 'Name1.1.2' },
              { id: '3', name: 'Name1.1.3' },
              ...
            ],
          },
          {
            name: 'Name1.2',
            items: [
              { id: '4', name: 'Name1.2.1' },
              { id: '5', name: 'Name1.2.2' },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'Name2',
        items: [
          {
            name: 'Name2.1',
            items: [
              { id: '6', name: 'Name2.1.1' },
              { id: '7', name: 'Name2.1.2' },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
```

I want to get the branch without the sibling elements, searching by id. The desired result is the next structure by id = '4':

```
let array = [
      {
        name: 'Name1',
        items: [
          {
            name: 'Name1.2',
            items: [
              { id: '4', name: 'Name1.2.1' },
            ],
          },
        ],
      }
    ];
```

I could find only the end element of the tree (`{ id: '4', name: 'Name1.2.1' }`). But I don't understand how to get intermediate structures of the tree.

```
const test = (data, id) => {
    if (!data || !data.length) return null;

    for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
      var result = data[j].items
        ? test(data[j].items, id)
        : data[j].id
        ? data[j].id === id
          ? data[j]
          : undefined
        : undefined;

      if (result !== undefined) {
        return result;
      }
    }

    return undefined;
  };

test(array, '4');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should indeed take a recursive approach, but your function currently can only return an `id` value (a string) or `null` or `undefined`. It never returns an array, yet that is what you expect to get.

When a solution is found as a base case, you need to wrap that solution in an array and plain object, each time you get out of the recursion tree.

Here is a working solution:

```js
function getPath(forest, targetid) {
    for (let root of forest) {
        if (root.id === targetid) return [root]; // base case
        let items = root.items && getPath(root.items, targetid);
        if (items) return [{ ...root, items }];  // wrap!
    }
}

// Example run:
let array = [{name: 'Name1',items: [{name: 'Name1.1',items: [{ id: '1', name: 'Name1.1.1' },{ id: '2', name: 'Name1.1.2' },{ id: '3', name: 'Name1.1.3' },],},{name: 'Name1.2',items: [{ id: '4', name: 'Name1.2.1' },{ id: '5', name: 'Name1.2.2' },],},],},{name: 'Name2',items: [{name: 'Name2.1',items: [{ id: '6', name: 'Name2.1.1' },{ id: '7', name: 'Name2.1.2' },],},],},];
console.log(getPath(array, '4'));
```